# Open auto complete on click on button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ofer's autocomplete in Angular2 app

https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer

I want a behavior where the auto complete does not open automatically upon typing but I need to press a button and only then should the autocomplete make a server request and show the dropdown I tried to implement CompleterData:

```
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import { HttpClient } from './shared';
import { CompleterData, CompleterItem } from 'ng2-completer';

export class AddressData extends Subject<CompleterItem[]> implements CompleterData {
    private url: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, public erpIDParent: number, url: string) {
        super();
        this.url = url;
    }

    public setErpIDParent(erpIDParent: number) {
        this.erpIDParent = erpIDParent;
    }

    public search(term: string): void {
        console.log('searching');
        if (this.erpIDParent > 0) {
            this.http.get(`${this.url}${term}&erpIDParent=${this.erpIDParent}`)
                .map((res: Response) => {
                    // Convert the result to CompleterItem[]
                    let data = res.json();
                    let matches: CompleterItem[] = data.map((address: any) => {
                        return {
                            originalObject: address,
                            title: address.Name
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(matches);
                    this.next(matches);
                })
                .subscribe();
        }
    }

    public cancel() {
        // Handle cancel
    }
}
```

and kept the minSearchLength to 1000

```
<ng2-completer placeholder="{{ 'NewOrder.typeToSearch' | translate }}" formControlName="address" [(ngModel)]="address" [datasource]="addressDataService" (selected)="addressSelected($event)" [minSearchLength]="1000"></ng2-completer>
```

so it wouldn't send the server request then on my button click I have this code:

```
searchAddresses() {
        this.addressDataService.search(this.address);
    }
```

so it would start the search manually but it doesn't seem to work the way I want to. The dropdown shows and hides instantly. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way although it's a workaround and not sure that the end result will be good enough.

You'll need a custom `CompleterData`component that will handle the search and this will provide you a way to control when to perform the search:

```
export class CustomData extends Subject<CompleterItem[]> implements CompleterData {

    public doSearch = false;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        super();
    }
    public search(term: string): void {
      if (this.doSearch) {
         this.http.get("http://example.com?term=" + term)
            .map((res: Response) => {
                // Convert the result to CompleterItem[]
                let data = res.json();
                let matches: CompleterItem[] = data.map((item: any) => this.convertToItem(item));
                this.next(matches);
            })
            .subscribe();
      } else {
        // if we don't do the search return empty results
        this.next([]);
      }
    }
}
```

Since search is called we need to prevent the display of searching and no results text so we set `textSearching` and `textNoResults` to false

```
<ng2-completer #completer [(ngModel)]="searchStr" [datasource]="datasource" [minSearchLength]="0" [textNoResults]="false" [textSearching]="false"></ng2-completer>
```

now when you want to do the search you can set `doSearch` on the data provider and it will start working.

the last part is to set the focus back to the completer and do the search again when it's activated:

in your component:

```
 @ViewChild("completer") private completer: CompleterCmp;

   protected startSearch() {
       this.datasource.doSearch = true;
       this.completer.focus();
       this.datasource.search(this.searchStr);
   }
```

here is a [plunker example](http://embed.plnkr.co/EXeSsb/)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you :)